# recv() does not block

Tags: c, ubuntu, recv

I have 2 machines running a simple C TCP server that I have written for testing purposes, 1 with Fedora 16, the other with Ubuntu 11.10.  My Fedora machine works perfectly but on the Ubuntu machine, recv() does not block.  Please keep in mind that these machines are running the same exact code.  Has anybody seen this before?  Thanks

```
int TcpSocket::ReadFromClient(int socket, char* buf, int len)
{
    char *request = buf;
    int slen = len;

    int c = recv(socket, request, slen, 0);
    while((c > 0) && (request[c-1] != '\n'))
    {
        request += c;
        slen -= c;
        c = recv(socket, request, slen, 0);
    }

    if (c < 0)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else if(c == 0)
    {
        //Sending back an empty string
        buf[0] = '\0';
    }

    return len-slen;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your socket is in nonblocking mode.

Comment: It returns 1 the first time (when it is actually sent data) and 0 while it is looping.  Why would it block on my fedora machine?

Comment: @tkcsam recv returning 0 means the other end closed the connection, or possibly that your `slen` argument to recv is 0.

Comment: I still don't understand why recv doesn't block the second time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the intention of your code is to stop reading when a `'\n'` byte arrives.  If that is the case then you need to read from the socket 1 byte at a time instead of using the entire available buffer size, especially since you are only checking the last byte of the buffer instead of checking every byte received.

You should also change the loop logic to only call `recv()` in one place instead of two places.  Your current implementation is calling recv() with `slen=0` when the buffer is exhausted, which will set `c=0` and nullify the first byte in the buffer.

Try this instead:

```
int TcpSocket::ReadFromClient(int socket, char* buf, int len)
{ 
    int slen = len;
    char ch;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        int ret = recv(socket, &ch, 1, 0); 
        if (ret > 0)
        {
            *buf = ch; 
            ++buf; 
            --len; 

            if (ch == '\n')
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((ret == 0) || (errno != EAGAIN))
                return ret;

            fd_set readfd;
            FD_ZERO(&readfd);
            FD_SET(socket, &readfd);

            timeval tv;
            tv.tv_sec = 5;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            ret = select(socket+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if (ret < 0)
                return ret;

            if (ret == 0)
            {
                // timeout elapsed while waiting for data
                // do something if desired...
            }
        } 
    } 

    return slen - len;
}
```

Comment: Either read one byte at a time and stop at newline, or read as much as possible, and break the received data into lines. The last method does require that leftover data is saved for the next read though.

Comment: Using a separate buffer to receive all inbound data, and thenbreaking up that buffer as neded, is more efficient in general and preferred whenever possible. Reading byte-by-byte is less efficient but is easier to code. So it is a trade-off between personal preference, efficiency, and code complexity.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Your code looks solid.  However, it still runs at 100% on my Ubuntu machine after the first connection.  Starting to wonder if there is something wrong with my machine.  Very strange.

Comment: Running at 100% CPU utilization is normal for this kind of looping, since there is nothing in this code to yield CPU slices.  That is why I added the comment about using `select()`.  That will put the loop to sleep, freeing up the CPU to do other things, until data actually arrives on the socket. If you do not want to use `select()`, then you can at least use `sleep()`.